# Gluon Charm down 3.0.0 - how to create cusom plugin

Tags: javafxports, gluon-mobile

How to create custom plugin in Gluon Charm down 3.0.0?
Or something similar.

I have package sk.ltorok.gluon.bluetooth.plugins and this package contains two classes BluetoothServiceFactory and BluetoothService and this is code:

```
package sk.ltorok.gluon.bluetooth.plugins;

import com.gluonhq.charm.down.DefaultServiceFactory;

public class BluetoothServiceFactory extends DefaultServiceFactory<BluetoothService> {

    public BluetoothServiceFactory() {
        super(BluetoothService.class);
    }  

}
```

... and next class

```
package sk.ltorok.gluon.bluetooth.plugins;

import java.util.List;

public interface BluetoothService {

    List<String> getPairedDevices();
}
```

In Basic view in constructor (I using Gluon Mobile) is this:

```
public class BasicView extends View {

    private BluetoothService bluetoothService;

    public BasicView(String name) {
        super(name);
        Services.registerServiceFactory(new BluetoothServiceFactory());
        System.out.println("REGISTER BLUETOOTH");
        boolean isPresent = Services.get(BluetoothService.class).isPresent();
        System.out.println("BLUETOOTH PRESENT: " + isPresent);
        if (isPresent) {
            Optional<BluetoothService> opt = Services.get(BluetoothService.class);
            bluetoothService = opt.get();
        }
```

... etc. next code ...

In Andoid/Java Packages folder I have package sk.ltorok.gluon.bluetooth.plugins.android and there is implementation AndroidBluetoothService class

```
package sk.ltorok.gluon.bluetooth.plugins.android;

import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Build;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;
import javafxports.android.FXActivity;
import sk.ltorok.gluon.bluetooth.plugins.BluetoothService;

public class AndroidBluetoothService implements BluetoothService {
    // ...
}
```

BUT isPresent is always false!

Comment: Gluon Charm Down was the primary driver for Gluon Mobile 4.0.0 and received a complete overhaul of API, a total overhaul of the packaging approach, and the simplification of third-party plugin development (and we hope third party developers will consider contributing their plugins back to the Gluon Charm Down project for the benefit of other users!)

Comment: Any simple sample - how to?

Comment: What could your question possibly be? SO is for solving specific programming problems - this is far too broad.

Comment: For starters you should have a look at Charm Down [code](https://bitbucket.org/gluon-oss/charm-down) and see how the different plugins are implemented. Then, provide your own service and its implementation, and register it via `Services.registerServiceFactory(CustomServiceFactory)`, then access the service at any time with: `Services.get(CustomService.class)`. Give it a try, and in case you have any question, post it here with the code you have tried.

Comment: CustomServiceFactory is extended from DefaultServiceFactory? See my code sample.

Comment: To add your own service, there are two options: one, provide your fully CustomServiceFactory and place it at any package you want; two, extend DefaultServiceFactory, but then you are forced to use the same package structure as in Down. In this case your service should be at this package: `com.gluonhq.charm.down.plugins`, and the platform implementation for Android under `com.gluonhq.charm.down.plugins.android`

Comment: So in the meantime I solved it already myself - I took option two. Thanks.