# How to play a sound on android using gluon (javafx project)

Tags: android, audio, gradle, gluon, javafxports

I am creating a javafx project. I ported it into Android using gluon.
Can someone tell me how can i play a sound on Android, because javafx media player isnt supported?

Regards

Comment: Check this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38419634/3956070). It needs to be updated with the current plugins approach, like in this other [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/40261409/3956070)

Comment: Yes but why i can't increase/decrease volume using physical button ;p ?

Comment: That's a known [issue](https://bitbucket.org/javafxports/android/issues/75/fxactivity-does-not-call), not solved yet.

Comment: so if it's not solved after 1 year, is there any solution for me ?

Comment: The project is open source. You can either contribute a patch for it, wait till is fixed, or you can ask for commercial support [here](http://gluonhq.com/services/commercial-support/).

Comment: I don't want to pay for support ;/ My programming skills are not enough to fix such problem :D

Comment: In the end, you need to dive into the code, see why this is happening and realize, that there are still other means to achieve this on Android.
I had the same issue (two years later, sigh) and solved like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40912656/cant-set-volume-volume-control-is-not-forwarded-to-the-system/40927831#40927831